# What is meaning 'talk in terms of something'?

Tags: american-english

What is meaning 'talk in terms of something'? I don't understand about this idiom. Does anyone know?

Comment: If you provide some example sentences this might be easier to answer.

Comment: talk by using special section terminology. For example, talk in terms of law - talk by using juristical terminologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Talk in terms of X' usually means having a conversation specifically focusing on and concerning X.

For example, to talk in terms of cost is to discuss the cost of whatever the subject matter is. You might ask someone "What are we talking in terms of cost?".